# Java school project issue with Maps

Tags: java, set, maps

I've been working on a school assignment.

The goal:

- I'm giving a list of supermarket customers
- Each customer has a zipcode and a Set with the Product names and a count on these products which this customer purchased.
- I'm being asked to return a Map (Sting = zipCode, Product = Product) which should contain the zipcode as the key and the product which is most sold for that zipcode.

The code I'm given:

```
/**
 * (DIFFICULT!!!)
 * calculates a map of most bought products per zip code that is also ordered by zip code
 * if multiple products have the same maximum count, just pick one.
 * @return
 */

public Map<String, Product> mostBoughtProductByZipCode() {
    Map<String, Product> mostBought = null;

    // TODO create an appropriate data structure for the mostBought and calculate its contents

    return mostBought;
}
```

I've been giving it a try with using a Map in a Map but having issues implementing this. This is far from complete and does not compile at all.

```
/**
 * (DIFFICULT!!!)
 * calculates a map of most bought products per zip code that is also ordered by zip code
 * if multiple products have the same maximum count, just pick one.
 * @return
 */
public Map<String, Product> mostBoughtProductByZipCode() {
    Map<String, Product> mostBought = null;
    Map<String, Map<Product, Integer>> zipCodeProducts = new HashMap<>();

    for (Customer customer : this.customers) {
        String tmp = customer.getZipCode();

        Map<Product, Integer> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Purchase purchase: customer.getItems()) {
            tmpMap.put(purchase.getProduct(),purchase.getAmount());
        }


        if (!zipCodeProducts.containsKey(tmp)){
            zipCodeProducts.put(tmp, tmpMap);
        } else {
            ???
        }

    }

    // TODO create an appropriate data structure for the mostBought and calculate its contents

    return mostBought;
}
```

What steps can I take to fix this implementation? I am just seeking hints rather than a completed solution.

Comment: Although it is tempting when working on academic work to ask for a full homework solution, you will learn a lot more if you can just get a hint. Having to do some thinking and solving is part of the process that your educator has set for you.

Comment: Hi halfer, I agree with you but this is just a small piece of a much larger school project. And tips is all i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but you need to think through what happens the first time you find a zip code / product combination.

There are quite a few `Map` methods to make this easier in later versions of Java. I'll use them here but if you have to use an earlier version then you'll need to expand some of these statements.

Something like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<Product, Integer>> zipCodeProducts = new HashMap<>();
for (Customer customer: customers) {
    Map<Product,Integer> productCounts = zipCodeProducts.computeIfAbsent(customer.getZipCode(), () -> new HashMap<>());
    for (Purchase purchase: customer.getItems()) {
        productCounts.merge(purchase.getProduct(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
}
```

Getting the product with the highest count should be relatively simple:

```
Map<String,Integer> maxProducts = new HashMap<>();
zipCodeProducts.forEach((zc, pc) -> pc.forEach((pr, n) -> {
    if (!maxProducts.contains(zc) || n > pc.get(maxProducts.get(zc)))
        maxProducts.put(zc, pr);
}));
```

Hope that makes sense - ask if not.

Comment: Hi Sprinter, Thanks a lot for this. I was able to solve my problem looking at your solution. I used something similar but i wouldnt have gotten there without this. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to move your if statement to the beginning of the for loop and only create `tmpMap` if it doesn't already exist for that zip code.  If it already exists, just use the existing one and update that with the products and amount.

```
for (Customer customer : this.customers) {
        String tmp = customer.getZipCode();
        Map<Product, Integer> tmpMap;

        if (!zipCodeProducts.containsKey(tmp)){
             tmpMap = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
        } else {
             tmpMap = zipCodeProducts.get(tmp);
        }


        for (Purchase purchase: customer.getItems()) {
            if (!tmpMap.containsKey(purchase.getProduct())) {
                tmpMap.put(purchase.getProduct(),purchase.getAmount());
            } else {
                tmpMap.put(purchase.getProduct(), tmpMap.get(purchase.getProduct()) + purchase.getAmount());
            }

        }

        zipCodeProducts.put(tmp, tmpMap);

    }
```